# Kobold / Cocos2D - Application becomes unresponsive after re-opening it after minimizing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, freeze, kobold2d

Currently I have a weird problem with a Kobold2D / Cocos2D game I'm developing on. Unfortunately there isn't really much to say, other than after minimizing the game on my iPad, as well as other iPads I've tested on, and then opening the process again through the process tray at the bottom of the screen, the game is unresponsive. That is, I can't hit buttons or anything like that, the application is just hanging. I do not get any crash reports through the debugger either, so it kind of looks like it might be a problem with the app delegate?

I've tried checking for potential missing methods in it, but can't find any from earlier projects that works with no problem.

I am wondering if anyone can point me in any direction for where I should search for the problem?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Which type of director are you using? And in your app delegate's handlers do you have the standard director pause/resume stuff?

Comment: I did figure out what the problem was :) The bug appeared for some odd reason if I used the *applicationDidBecomeActive:* method in the AppDelegate, it simply made the application unable to resume itself properly. I'm not sure what the underlying reason is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was :) The bug appeared for some odd reason if I used the applicationDidBecomeActive: method in the AppDelegate, it simply made the application unable to resume itself properly. I'm not sure what the underlying reason is